# 2D-Array deletes elements itself when new elements get stored

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino

edit: I didn't initialise the array with the right size. I should have used 8 instead of 7. I had to learn that Arrays start counting at 0, but when initialising the don't!

I have a 2 dimensional Array storage[x][y] and want to store for each x value 8 different y values. For some reason I can read out a specific place in the array, for example [48][7] and after filling other spaces in the array the [48][7] value has changed even tough I never touched it.

```
int storage[127][7];

void store(){
 storage[48][0] =0b01111110;
 storage[48][1] =0b01111110;
 storage[48][2] =0b11100011;
 storage[48][3] =0b11010011;
 storage[48][4] =0b11001011;
 storage[48][5] =0b11000111;
 storage[48][6] =0b01111110;
 storage[48][7] =0b01111110;


   Serial.println(storage[48][7], BIN); // returns 01111110

 storage[49][0] =0b00000000;
 storage[49][1] =0b11000001;
 storage[49][2] =0b11000001;
 storage[49][3] =0b11111111;
 storage[49][4] =0b11111111;
 storage[49][5] =0b00000001;
 storage[49][6] =0b00000001;
 storage[49][7] =0b00000000;

   Serial.println(storage[48][7], BIN); // returns 0
}
```

Depending on the order in which I store the values some of them delete each other.

Why do I suddenly lose data?

Comment: please create a [MCVE]. What is the type of `storage`?

Comment: We have no idea what `storage` is.

Comment: sorry... better now?

Comment: For array `int storage[7]` the maximum index you can access is `6`

Comment: `int storage[127][7];` -- This is an out-of-bounds access: `Serial.println(storage[48][7] ,BIN);`.  Array indexing starts from 0 and go to `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of entries.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you so much! Beginner mistake. I knew arrays start at 0, and i kinda assumed they would start counting there ;)

Comment: `int storage[128][8];` needs 2048 bytes of memory and an Arduino Uno has only same 2048 bytes of available memory.

Comment: @gre_gor i'm using the mega ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a 2D-array with row-size `7`, but you access 8 elements of a single row:

```
 int storage[127][7];

 storage[48][0] =0b01111110;
 ...
 storage[48][7] =0b01111110;
```

Note that 0..7 are actually 8 elements, not 7. So you'd have to define `storage` as...

```
 int storage[127][8];
```

One might discuss now if `int storage[127][7];storage[48][7] =0b01111110` is undefined behaviour;

Yet the most probably behaviour is that `storage[48][7]` maps to the same memory address as `storage[49][0]`. Hence, when you assign `storage[49][0] =0b00000000;`, then you write to `storage[48][7]` "as well" and it will become `0b0000000`.